# JavaScript - Using selenium-webdriver what returns the inner html to a variable?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here are a few examples I have tried based on my past Python projects (here I am using JavaScript)...

```
var eltext = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('el')).text;
console.log(elname);

var eltext = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('el')).innerText;
console.log(elname);

var eltext = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('el')).innerHTML;
console.log(elname);
```

I have also tried a few other ways using `String()`, `JSON.stringify()`, and various for loops, spinning out on my options. I can do a `.click()` and this object is clickable, so I know my selector is right, but the accessing the inner text in JavaScript is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://www.example.com');

var el = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName('div'));

// Get the text of the element using getText...
el.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});

// The code above could be shortened to this:
// el.getText().then(console.log);

// Get the inner HTML of the element using getInnerHtml...
el.getInnerHtml().then(function (html) {
    console.log(html);
});

// The code above could be shortened to this:
// el.getInnerHtml().then(console.log);

// Get the text browser side plus the innerHTML at the same time.
driver.executeScript('\
var el = arguments[0];\
return {text: el.innerText, html: el.innerHTML};\
', el).then(function (val) {
    console.log(val.text);
    console.log(val.html);
});

driver.quit();
```

You have to use `.then` because the methods do not return the value itself but a *promise* to get the value.

The last method with `executeScript` gets the two values at the same time. If you wonder why one would bother with `executeScript`, the reason is that each call to `getText` and `getInnerHtml` means a round trip between the Selenium client (your script) and the Selenium server (the browser). On large test suites these round trips accumulate and can add **minutes** to the run time of the suite. I've also put it there to show that you can run any JavaScript you want on the browser by using this method.

Comment: I up-voted for the informative answer and will confirm in the morning with my project. If true, this looks look it just shared some magic for a lot of my issues with promises.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a [`WebElement`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html) from Selenium, not a DOM [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), so don't attempt to use DOM API you know from the browser. Selenium is a different pair of shoes.

[Selenium web driver docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html) point to  `getText()` or `getInnerHtml()`.

Comment: It is giving me the findElement object `{ then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }`

Comment: That's correct, you're obtaining a [Promise](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_promise_Promise.html). Promises are becoming standard in Javasript nowadays, so you'll easily find some docs on how to work with them